# RabbitMQ competing consumers processing 1 message at a time sequentially

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, fifo

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607967/process-messages-sequentially-with-competing-consumers), we have FIFO queues and the messages must be processed in order. We want competing consumers from different machines for redundancy and performance reasons, but only one consumer on one machine should handle a message for a given queue at a time.

I tried setting the prefetch count to 1, but I believe this will only work if used with a single machine. Is this possible by default with RabbitMQ or do we need to implement our own lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a single queue with multiple consumers there is no way to block one of the consumers, all of them receive the messages in round-robin fashion.

**EDIT**
See https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#single-active-consumer
**/EDIT**

You could see this plugin, https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange to distribute the load using different queues.

> I tried setting the prefetch count to 1

`prefetch=1` means that the consumers take one message at a time.

> do we need to implement our own lock

Yes, If you want **one single** consumer for queue avoiding other consumers.

**EDIT**

There are also the `Exclusive Queues` https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#exclusive-queues but **note**:

> Exclusive queues are deleted when their declaring connection is closed or gone (e.g. due to underlying TCP connection loss). They, therefore, are only suitable for client-specific transient state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd taken a look at exclusive queues, but hadn't seen the caveat about them being deleted.
I'm not sure if the consistent hashing plugin would help - I don't think it ensures serial execution and that's my main concern. 
The tip about them currently developing the feature looks interesting

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but it might help someone else who comes across this.

You can declare a Queue with the argument `x-single-active-consumer=true`.  This means you can have multiple consumers for redundancy while only one of them consumes messages.  If the active consumer disconnects, the next consumer will be chosen as the active consumer.

You can read more about this here: [https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#:~:text=Single%20active%20consumer%20allows%20to,they%20arrive%20in%20the%20queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#:%7E:text=Single%20active%20consumer%20allows%20to,they%20arrive%20in%20the%20queue).

A little warning, be careful doing this.  Single Active Consumers can easily become a bottleneck.  Your message throughput is limited by the time it takes to process a single message.